# How can I load external pages in the same tab with twitter-bootstrap framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find examples of "first senario" in [Basic tabs example](http://bootstrap.stage42.net/doc/navigation) on Tabs used as regular navigation (loading external pages in the same tab).

I've this tabs :

```
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li class='active'><a href='/' id=''>All Repos</a></li>
    <li><a href='/cms/watchers' id='cms'>CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href='/css/watchers' id='css'>CMS</a></li>
    <li><a href='/ruby/watchers' id='ruby'>CMS</a></li>
    <li><a href='/framework/watchers' id='framework'>CMS</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**"All Repos"**, is active by default, but when I click **cms** for example, I get the page but the tab doesn't get active.

Here the rest of the page I get back :

```
  <div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='active tab-pane' id='cms'></div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr class='row'>
            <th>repo</th>
            <th>watchers</th>
            <th>forks</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>created</th>
            <th>pushed</th>
            <th>tags</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class='row'>
            <td>
              <a href="https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll">mojombo/jekyll</a>
            </td>
            <td>4473</td>
            <td>715</td>
            <td>Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby</td>
            <td>Mon, Oct 20 at  6:29am</td>
            <td>Sun, Nov 27 at  2:48am</td>
            <td class='4ee287831d41c8281f000166'>cms</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    //<![CDATA[
      $(function () {
        $('.tabs').tabs()
      })
    //]]>
  </script>
```

I need to have tabs containing pages (not relative content insight the page), something like the following example: http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/balls, but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Comment: ok, I already see that, but in my case I don't have a relative URI/anchor pointing to #part-of-the-doc but an absolute URI pointing to a new page. How do I reference the href="/cms/watchers" ? What 'id= ...' is like in <div class="tab-pane" id=" ... "> ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'm actually not sure, and it's not in the documentation. The easiest way to figure that out, is to use a Web Inspector / Firebug type tool to look at the id given to those divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming form others js plug-in behaviors, I didn't realize it was so simple.

Thanks to [jasny](https://github.com/jasny) for clarifying :

[If you're loading different pages there is no need for the javascript, as you can simply output the correct HTML. So solving it in your server side code (Ruby, PHP, Phyton or whatever).](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/814#issuecomment-3187498)

```
  <!-- URL: / -->
  <ul class='tabs' data-tabs='tabs'>
    <li class='active'><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cms/watchers">CMS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/watchers">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ruby/watchers">Ruby</a></li>
    <li><a href="/framework/watchers">Framework</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- URL: /cms/watchers -->
  <ul class='tabs' data-tabs='tabs'>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href="/cms/watchers">CMS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/watchers">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ruby/watchers">Ruby</a></li>
    <li><a href="/framework/watchers">Framework</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[So only use the javascript if you want to be able to switch tabs without reloading the page.](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/814#issuecomment-3187498)